# Como obter o bairro por meio da geolocalização?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-1, geolocalização

Todos os outros campos retornam normalmente através da geolocalização, apenas o bairro vem em branco. O que está errado?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Talvez ele simplesmente não possua informações de bairro na sua localidade? Já testou em outro lugar ou tem como confrontar com outra aplicação que utiliza o serviço de geo localização do WP?

Comment: Já testei em outros locais, mas a maioria não retorna o bairro,acho que apenas um retornou ,mas era uma localidade dos estados unidos, mas acho estranho não retornar, porque até o numero e o nome da rua retorna, mas o bairro não. Antes na verdade eu estava tentando usar a api do google, mas estou com dificuldade para fazer a leitura no c# do json que ele retorna

Comment: Como funcionou para alguma localidade, o problema provavelmente é que eles não possuem informação de bairros para os locais que você esta pesquisando. Isto não seria tão estranho, já que no BR, os correios monopolizam informações públicas. Isso sem contar que monópolis são explicitamente proibidos pela constituição... mas isso é um outro problema hehehe...

Answer (score 1):

você deve usar District para bairro e não Neighborhood, mas isso depende da localização. tem lugares nos Estados Unidos que ele retorna Neighborhood.
eu uso assim:

```
Bairro = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Locations[0].Address.Neighborhood) ? result.Locations[0].Address.District : result.Locations[0].Address.Neighborhood;
```

Comment: Tentei usar o District aqui mas ele retorna vazio também